# How do I use a Scanner to read a number of characters including white spaces?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I use a Scanner to read a number of characters including white spaces? I have a file that's full of:

```
  937 216 316 O 1041.1
```

lines. I tried to pull out each one like this, but it didn't work for me.

```
 if (sc.hasNextLine) {
 String s = sc.nextLine();
 String type = sc.next();
 double num = sc.nextDouble();
```

If you can help me fix the above, AWESOME! Otherwise I'm trying to pul out by char, for instance
I want to assing String s the from charcter 1 to 11 as a string and so on.

Sorry if I am confusing you, will be here to reply any comments.

Thanks

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: There are two common approaches.  Either get rid of the `nextLine()` and just get each field individually from the scanner; or use `nextLine()` to get the whole line, and then `split` to divide it into fields.  If your format is very regular, you could use the first approach.  If there are different fields on each line, the second approach would probably be better.

Comment: Or at least post more code, enough for us to run.  But I probably would not use Scanner for this.  A BufferedReader and the readLine() method are likely your best bet.

Comment: @DavidWallace What do you mean "get each field individually from the Scanner". And yes my format is regular.

Comment: I mean, you've written code like `String type = sc.next();
 double num = sc.nextDouble();` which would work well for you if you hadn't preceded them with `sc.nextLine()`.  As it is, you're trying to pull the same information out of your scanner twice.